# how use JOOQ plain SQL templating?

Tags: java, spring, jooq

postgres query :

```
select * from message t  where "address" = decode('0x159159159526212521','escape')
```

develop code :

```
Field<String> address = val("0x159159159526212521");
Field<String> escape = val("escape");

rdbmsJooqContext.select(
            al.NAME.as("name"),
            al.ADDRESS.as("address")
    ).from(al)
            .where(
                    condition(" 'address' = decode({0}, {1})", address, escape)
            ).fetchInto(AddressLabelResult.class);
```

jooq query result:

```
where ( 'address' = decode('0x159159159526212521', 'escape'))
```

i want to jooq query result:

```
where 'address' = decode('0x159159159526212521', 'escape')
```

how delete "where sql" '(' and ')' ??

Comment: Why does it matter to you? The parentheses are mostly cosmetic in this case...

Comment: you right!! was just curious. thanks for your answering. jooq is very smart application. i love jooq develop team.

Answer (score 0):

### Why did you get the parentheses:

When you use plain SQL templates of a certain type, like `Condition`, jOOQ will always wrap them in parentheses to make sure the template doesn't get broken by operator precedence rules. Imagine e.g.

```java
al.NAME.eq("x").and(  condition("something or something_else")  )
```

As you can see, the plain SQL template is passed to the `and()` method, so the expectation is that its contents should have a higher precedence than the `AND` operator. In this case, you want the outcome to be:

```sql
name = 'x' and (  something or something_else  )
```

Not this (where `and` now has higher precedence than `or`):

```sql
name = 'x' and something or something_else
```

The assumption being that these parentheses sometimes being unnecessary being only a cosmetic problem, like in your case.

### How to work around this

If you really don't like the parentheses around the predicate, you could work around it e.g. by writing this:

```java
inline("address").eq(field("decode({0}, {1})", String.class, address, escape)
```

The same parenthesising logic isn't implemented for `Field` templates at the same location.